# Performance gains from fast multiplication with bit shifting

Tags: performance, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, multiplication

I have been reading a lot of articles lately about programming practice, design and so forth and was curious about the real performance gains from implementing multiplication as bit shifting.

The example I was reading about was encouraging implementing x*320 as (x<<8 + x<<6) for a commonly used routine.

How relevant is this in modern compilers? If there are significant performance gains, can compilers not automatically convert these "easy multiplications" to bit-shifts as necessary?

Has anyone had to resort to bit-shifting in this way in their projects to achieve faster multiplication? What performance gains can you expect?

Comment: Since you're asking "what performance gains can you expect?", discussing this kind of thing can really mislead you, because *any* kind of micro optimization can only matter in tight CPU loops that you get to compile and that actually see much use. This is only a very special category of code. Most apps that people compile spend nearly all their time in system libraries, I/O, DB access, etc. etc. They can be optimized, but only by eliminating function calls that are on the stack a large fraction of time. Compilers can't do that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, compilers will do most of these for you. They're pretty aggressive with it too. So there's rarely a need to do it yourself. (especially at the cost of readability)

However, on modern machines now, multiplication isn't "that" much slower than shifts. So any number that needs more than like 2 shifts are better done using multiplication. The compilers know this and will choose accordingly.

EDIT:

From my experience, I've never been able to outdo a compiler in this area unless the code was vectorized via SSE intrinsics (which the compilers don't really try to optimize).

Comment: Great answer, clear and all. I'm just curious: has this been something that has improved a lot in recent years? The article I mentioned in my question was a good ~16 years old and referred particularly to VS6 a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure about recently. For as long as I've been active (~5 years), compilers have always been doing this optimization. But I can imagine these "strength reduction" optimizations to be a lot older than that.

Comment: Used this trick in 16-bit assembly 17-18 years ago. It was a lot faster back then, not sure how it would compare to SSE instructions on a 64-bit x86 today.